# Как сохранить изображение в центре при анимации масштабирования?

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация

У меня  ситуация, подобная этому [примеру](https://jsfiddle.net/ddvn3p1h/3/), где у меня есть анимация `CSS3`, которая масштабирует элемент, `absolute-positioned`, расположенный в центре другого элемента.

Однако, когда начинается анимация то, она находится вне центра, как видно по красным квадратам относительно синего в примере.

Как я могу отцентрировать их? Я попробовал пару конфигураций вокруг свойства
 `transform-origin`, но это не дает правильных результатов.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ripple_large {
  0% {-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
  75% {-webkit-transform:scale(3); opacity:0.4;}
  100% {-webkit-transform:scale(4); opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes ripple_large {
  0% {transform:scale(1); }
  75% {transform:scale(3); opacity:0.4;}
  100% {transform:scale(4); opacity:0;}
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10vmax;
}

.cat {
  height: 20vmax;
}

.center-point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.to-animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5vmax;
  width: 5vmax;
  transform-origin:center;
}

.one {
  -webkit-animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

.two {
  -webkit-animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820827/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что вы удаляете translate `transformation`.

Когда вы указываете новое `transformation`, оно переопределяет первую трансформацию, поэтому вам нужно добавить их в одно и то же свойство преобразования.

В вашем случае вы удаляете `translation`, который фиксирует выравнивание по центру:

```css
@keyframes ripple_large {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1) ;
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(3) ;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%)  scale(4) ;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10vmax;
}

.cat {
  height: 20vmax;
}

.center-point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  transform-origin:center;
}

.to-animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5vmax;
  width: 5vmax;
}

.one {
  -webkit-animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

.two {
  -webkit-animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pixiebob-cat.jpg' class='cat'>
  <div class='center-point'>
  </div>
  <div class='to-animate one'></div>
  <div class='to-animate two'></div>
</div>
```

Источник: [How to keep origin in center of image in scale animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47820893/7394871) @Temani Afif